# How to determine a log's source process spawned from a systemd service?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I have a systemd service which starts multiple 3rd-party processes which output to standard output. Is there anyway to easily determine which logs are from specific process from the system journal?

---

Diving into systemd recently, I had a question about logging. `man systemd-journald.service` notes that:

> It creates and maintains structured, indexed journals based on logging information that is received from the kernel, from user processes via the libc syslog(3) call, **from standard input and standard error of system services** or via its native API.

I created a simple service:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/myself/logtest/runlogtest
```

And have the script invoke some processes:

```
#!/bin/bash

...
/home/myself/logtest/app1 &
/home/myself/logtest/app2 &
...
```

When the service is running, I listen for messages using the following command:

```
journalctl -f | grep runlogtest
```

The output is seen as the following (for this example, app1 output 'A' and app2 output 'B'):

```
Aug 07 14:22:04 localhost.localdomain runlogtest[8742]: B
Aug 07 14:22:07 localhost.localdomain runlogtest[8742]: A
Aug 07 14:22:07 localhost.localdomain runlogtest[8742]: B
Aug 07 14:22:10 localhost.localdomain runlogtest[8742]: B
Aug 07 14:22:11 localhost.localdomain runlogtest[8742]: A
Aug 07 14:22:13 localhost.localdomain runlogtest[8742]: B
Aug 07 14:22:15 localhost.localdomain runlogtest[8742]: A
```

Is there anyway to know that 'A' logs are coming from app1 (and 'B' messages are from app2)?

The only solutions I can see right now is that I would:

- Manage each application in its own service (something I'd like to avoid).
- Make a wrapper for process which I capture their standard output and pump to the journal via syslog.

Comment: Have you considered adding `ps aux | grep 'bash.*<script name>' | tee -a <your log file>` to your apps? This will add the pid to the log file for identification. Similarly, you can `echo` the output before each app output to CMD.

Comment: I should add that this will also add the process name to the log file; hence it'll give you direct relation between process log and process/app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Make a wrapper for process which I capture their standard output and pump to the journal via syslog.

Such wrapper already exists and is called [`systemd-cat`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cat.html).

You may use it as follows:

```
systemd-cat -t app1 /home/myself/logtest/app1 &
systemd-cat -t app2 /home/myself/logtest/app2 &
```

The argument to `-t` is an arbitrary identification string, analogous (equivalent) to syslog's identifier.

It is also possible to use `systemd-cat` in a shell pipeline like this:

```
/home/myself/logtest/app1 |& systemd-cat -t app1 &
```

(The `|&` is a bash construction to pipeline both stdout and stderr.)

However, the first form is preferable as it avoids spawning an extra process and doing an extra copy of all logged data.